# () (Function) not working when defined in a class and called

Tags: android, flutter, function, android-studio, dart

I have a class CustomDrawer that defines how and what the drawer should look like and implement.
I am calling this : CustomDrawer(Icons.arrow_left, 'Back', () => Get.back())
from class CustomDrawer but when I tap the left arrow icon, it does not function or the drawer does not get back to the previous page.

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  IconData icon;
  String text;
  Function GoTap;
  CustomDrawer(this.icon, this.text, this.GoTap);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))

        ),
        child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
            onTap: () => GoTap,
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(icon),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            text,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                ],
              ),
            ))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the line from `onTap: () => GoTap,` to `onTap: GoTap,`

Comment: Thanks dude. It worked superb. A great help indeed.